# failover in quickfix engine c++

Tags: c++, quickfix, fix-protocol

During fail-over when fix try to connect sockethost1:socketport1 instead of  sockethost:socketport , why it always wait for 30s in between and how to reduce this time.

Configuration file  [from quickfix engine page](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/configuration.html)

```
  # default settings for sessions
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=60
SenderCompID=TW

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.2
TargetCompID=INCA
StartTime=12:30:00
EndTime=21:30:00
# overide default setting for RecconnectInterval
ReconnectInterval=30
HeartBtInt=30
SocketConnectPort=6523
SocketConnectHost=3.3.3.3
# (optional) alternate connection ports and hosts to cycle through on failover
SocketConnectPort1=8392
SocketConnectHost1=8.8.8.8
SocketConnectPort2=2932
SocketConnectHost2=12.12.12.12
DataDictionary=somewhere/FIX42.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got

```
ReconnectInterval=30
```

and that is probably the reason

Comment: I tried different value for ReconnectInterval , but what I found that it has no effect.

Comment: I tried but it is not working, seems like ReconnectInterval is doing nothing.

Comment: Take out the ReconnectInterval under [DEFAULT] and only use the one in [SESSION]